# How to Routes:: group

Tags: php, laravel

Error says

all to undefined function group()

at C:\laragon\www\OnlineComplianceManagement\routes\web.php:32
28|      return view('loginblade');
29|   // Route::get('/index','Modules/Login/Http/Controllers/LoginController@index');
30|   });
31|

> 32| Route:group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){
> 33|       //Route::get('login/index','LoginController@index');
> 34|       Route::get('LoginModel', 'MainLoginController@index');
> 35|
> 36|   });

1   C:\laragon\www\OnlineComplianceManagement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar.php:35
require()

2   C:\laragon\www\OnlineComplianceManagement\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:417
Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::register("C:\laragon\www\OnlineComplianceManagement\routes/web.php")

my code

```
Route:group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){     
        Route::get('LoginModel', 'MainLoginController@index');   
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled on `:` **(colon)** , Should be `::` **(double colon)** :

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){     
   Route::get('LoginModel', 'MainLoginController@index');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not using routes in api.php and web.php
Try to write use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], static function () {
    Route::get('LoginModel', 'MainLoginController@index');
}
```

Another way

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(static function () {
    Route::get('LoginModel', 'MainLoginController@index');
});
```

Comment: thanks @Hackimov it works. i guess api and web routes are different in setting up the route